# php mosaic script

Tags: php, gdlib

I'm using a script that I downloaded from google code to dynamically generate mosaic images with the GD library. The script seems a bit convoluted. I've messed around with it quite a bit, but I'm sort of confused since it's written in German and I don't speak deutsch. I know that in order for it to work, I need to have 121 different images. But, I'm not sure if they needs to be in the directory or in mysql. Does anyone have a clue as to how to use this? Or does anyone have some suggestions for a better script for generating mosaic images with the php GD library?

The script can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/phpmosaic/

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: You have a script, you don't tell us what it is, or where it is. You don't provide any code samples, yet we're supposed to be able to magically fix it for you, sight unseen? We're good, but not THAT good...

Comment: I knew i forgot something... :)

Comment: @Lance: did you solved your problem please?

Answer (score 0):

The images you like to use as thumbnails have to be inside a directory. You must add them to the db using the methods

- phpMosaicImageParser::parseImageFolder() or
- phpMosaicImageParser::parseImage()

However: there is no fix number of required thumbnails,  it will depend on the SourceImage and the used options how much thumbnails you'll need at least.

Comment: I have them inside that directory and it's still giving me errors in German. Did you download the code? Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, currently my PC is broken, I'm not able to test anything on a webserver. What errors do you receive?(I'm familiar with "deutsch" and may translate)