# Create "arty" mosaic pictures with R (*not* statistical mosaic plots)

Tags: r, graphics, color-picker

I'd like to play around with images a bit and wondered if there are ways in R to produce **mosaic pictures** like [these](http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/14/1430/CM4R000Z/posters/bob-marley-mosaic.jpg).

I guess for the background image one could use `readJPEG` (package [jpeg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jpeg/index.html)) and `rasterImage` from package `graphics`.

But I'm lost with respect to how to compute and cluster color values etc. in order to arrange the foreground pictures.

### EDIT

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602314/php-mosaic-script) which goes "in the right direction". But I guess if you create a "true" mosaic where the actual picture is purely made up of small pictures (as opposed to having a combination of background and foreground pictures and finding the right amount of transparency as in [this example](http://www.engadget.com/2004/10/19/how-to-make-your-own-photo-mosaics/)), you have the problem that you'll need hundreds or possibly even thousands of pictures.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thought this was a nice challenge to waste a few hours on. Here is a proof of concept function:

```
library(jpeg)
library(png)
library(plyr)

reduceCol <-  function(x,dim=c(1,1))
{
  arr <- array(dim=c(nrow(x),ncol(x),4))
  cols <- col2rgb(c(x),alpha=TRUE)
  arr[,,1] <- matrix(cols[1,],nrow(x),ncol(x),byrow=TRUE)
  arr[,,2] <- matrix(cols[2,],nrow(x),ncol(x),byrow=TRUE)
  arr[,,3] <- matrix(cols[3,],nrow(x),ncol(x),byrow=TRUE)
  arr[,,4] <- matrix(cols[4,],nrow(x),ncol(x),byrow=TRUE)



  Res <- array(dim=c(dim,4))
  if (dim[1]>1) seqRows <- as.numeric(cut(1:nrow(x),dim[1])) else seqRows <- rep(1,nrow(x))
  if (dim[2]>1) seqCols <- as.numeric(cut(1:ncol(x),dim[2])) else seqCols <- rep(1,ncol(x))


  for (i in 1:dim[1])
  {
    for (j in 1:dim[2])
    { 
      for (z in 1:4)
      {
        Res[i,j,z] <- mean(arr[seqRows==i,seqCols==j,z])
      }
    }
  }
  return(Res)
}

rgbarr2colmat <- function(mat) 
{
  Res <- array(dim=dim(mat)[1:2])
  for (i in 1:dim(mat)[1])
  {
    for (j in 1:dim(mat)[2])
    {
      Res[i,j] <- rgb(mat[i,j,1],mat[i,j,2],mat[i,j,3],mat[i,j,4],maxColorValue=255)
    }
  }
  return(Res)
}

artymosaic <- function(BG,pics,res=c(10,10))
{
  BGreduced <- reduceCol(BG,res)
  Picmeancol <- lapply(pics,reduceCol)

  blockPic <- array(dim=res)
  for (i in 1:res[1])
  {
    for (j in 1:res[2])
    {
      blockPic[i,j] <- which.min(sapply(Picmeancol,function(x)sum(abs(BGreduced[i,j,]-x))))
    }
  }
  blockPic <- t(blockPic)
  blockPic <- blockPic[,ncol(blockPic):1]

  # Open empty plot:
  par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
  plot(1,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),type="n",bty="n",axes=FALSE)

  # plot moasics:
  seqRows <- seq(0,1,length=res[1]+1)
  seqCols <- seq(0,1,length=res[2]+1)
  for (i in 1:res[1])
  {
    for (j in 1:res[2])
    {
      rasterImage(pics[[blockPic[i,j]]],seqRows[i],seqCols[j],seqRows[i+1],seqCols[j+1],interpolate=FALSE)
    }
  }
}
```

`artymosaic` uses the background in raster format as first argument, a list of pictures in raster format as second and the resolution (numeric(2)) as third argument.

An example with the R logo made up of pictures of computers. I downloaded some pictures of google and uploaded them at http://sachaem47.fortyseven.versio.nl/files/pics/mosaic.zip. If these are extracted in a mosaic folder, and the R logo (http://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg) is downloaded in the working directory, we can make the "arty mosaic" as follows.

```
bg <- readJPEG("Rlogo.jpg")
BG <- as.raster(bg)

jpgs <- lapply(list.files("mosaic/",pattern="\\.jpg",full.names=TRUE),readJPEG)
pics <- lapply(jpgs,as.raster)

png("test.png")
artymosaic(BG,pics,c(50,50))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Looks spectacular right? The major drawback here is that I reuse the same image where appropriate and that I only used very few images. That could be changed but would require much much more images, which will cause the function to run much longer. Again, proof of concept.

Comment: I'm curious to see what you will make of it. Maybe you can post it to R-bloggers when done?